# Error Installing '@google-cloud/artifactregistry' with Yarn: "Not found"

Tags: npm, google-artifact-registry

I'm facing an issue while attempting to install the @google-cloud/artifactregistry package using Yarn, and I'm encountering the following error message:

`error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@google-cloud%2fartifactregistry: Not found". info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/alameen/bravosoft/backoffice-v2-be/yarn-error.log". info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.`

Steps to Reproduce:

Run yarn add @google-cloud/artifactregistry in your terminal.
Expected Results:

I expect the package to be installed without any errors.

Actual Results:

The error message mentioned above occurs.

Background:

Operating System: ubuntu 20.14
Yarn Version: 1.22.19
Node.js Version: 18.16.0

I was trying npm package is published to Artifact Registry and able to do it using NPM publish and when I tried this NPM get registry I am getting this

`https://registry.npmjs.org/`

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?
Is there any relation between me publishing package and this error
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!